# Copying Domain Users and Creating stream_autocomplete in Outlook 2010

Tags: batch-file

We have a client who is about to be migrated. Basically, I am going to log in as each of the users and run a batch file to copy their stuff using xcopy.

Just as an example, below will copy Desktop and the RoamCache folder:

```
xcopy "\\server\%username%.v2\Desktop" "%userprofile%\Desktop" /e /c /q /r

xcopy "\\server\%username%.v2\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache" "%userprofile%\Outlook" /e /c /q /r
```

First question - is there a more efficient way of running this batch file, logged in as the domain Administrator account, and using a for loop to copy the users? Or will I run into permission issues as the Administrator needs to be the folder owner first?

My second issue is this - since MS Outlook 2010 uses the stream_autocomplete.dat files instead of .nk2, I am trying to write a batch file to 1. Open Outlook, 2. Send an email so a stream_autocomplete.dat file is created, 3. Close Outlook

So far I have got the below which starts Outlook and creates the email but I do not know how to send that email and close Outlook.

```
START /b "Microsoft Outlook" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"

START mailto:email@bla.com?subject=CreateAutocompleteˆ&
```

The end product I want is, for Outlook 2010 on the new server to open, create the stream_autocomplete.dat file by sending an email, close Outlook, the old stream_autocomplete.dat file to be copied into the new RoamCache folder, renamed as the new .dat file and the other .dat file to be deleted.

Please note that I am a total rookie with this stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Doing a bit more research, I don't think there is an easy way of sending the email using batch. Instead I have adapted the below vbscript code to do everything I wanted it to from 1. Starting Outlook, 2. Creating the email, 3. Sending the email, 4. Closing, reopening and closing (sometimes the stream_autocomplete.dat file doesn't get created after the first close) –  bertrix May 28 at 5:10

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) 
objMail.Display objMail.to = "email@bla.com" 
objMail.Subject = "Create Autocomplete" 
objMail.Send objOutlook.Quit 
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) 
objMail.Display 
objOutlook.Quit 
Set objMail = Nothing 
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not paste code snippets in comments; [edit] your question rather...

Comment: I would post this question to SuperUser.  However, you'll have better luck copying the user profile except •Ntuser.dat •Ntuser.dat.log •Ntuser.ini